# Format to POST a file to the ImageKit server?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, imagekit

I've successfully built a React UI to select and upload N files.  The key part of it is this:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' id='selectFiles' multiple onChange={handleFileChange} />
```

The selected files are stored in this state variable:

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = React.useState<FileList>();
```

I know they're correctly there because I iterate through them and show them in a preview DIV.

Following ImageKit's instructions, I successfully built an Auth endpoint which returns the auth credentials.

Then, within a `useEffect` I iterated through `fileList` to upload one photo at a time to the ImageKit server.  But even trying just one file, I keep getting a 400 error informing me that the `fileName` parameter is missing.  It definitely is not missing so I suspect that the problem lies with what I'm providing as the `file` parameter.

Here's the critical code (with some data obscured for privacy reasons) :

```
    const uploadFile = async (file: File) => {
      try {
        const body = {
          file: file,
          publicKey: 'my_public_key',
          signature: 'imageKit_signature',
          expire: 'imageKit_expiry_value',
          token: 'imageKit_token',
          fileName: 'test123.jpg',
          useUniqueFileName: false,
          folder: userName,
          overwriteFile: false,
        };

        const response = await axios.post('https://upload.imagekit.io/api/v1/files/upload', body);
        console.log(response.status, response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };
```

Might anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Robert

Comment: I've played around further with the "File to Base64` code.  Here's what I'm now sending to the ImageKit endpoint but still getting the same `missing fileName parameter` error:

file: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4TsqRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA..."
fileName: "abc.jpg"
folder: "test"
overwriteFile: false

Comment: Note: This is the start of the `file` property and its contents: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4TsqRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIAA8BA

Chrome also tells me that these contents are 2.4MB, which is the correct filesize I'm trying to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  If you're going to upload a file to ImageKit using their POST endpoint, you need to explicitly set the `headers` like this:

```
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://upload.imagekit.io/api/v1/files/upload', 
  body, 
  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} }
);
```

For those wondering, here's the barebones `body`:

```
const body = {
  file: base64File,
  publicKey: imageKitPublicKey,
  signature: authParams?.signature,
  expire: authParams?.expire,
  token: authParams?.token,
  fileName: 'someFilename.ext',
};
```

But indeed, specifying `Content-Type` like above will allow you to upload a file to their server.